# CSI differential pairs differential impedance : follow Jetson design guide or standard 100R value?

Tags: impedance, differential, camera, csi

I'm designing a PCB based on the Jetson Orin NX system on module, using a camera (MIPI CSI PHY-D).

The problem is that the [design guide of the Jetson](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/embedded/secure/jetson/orin_nx/docs/Jetson_Orin_NX_Series_and_Orin_Nano_Series_Design_Guide_DG-10931-001_v1.1.pdf?GsWFipMxW1RYTeY5j8xE3DrFPUAlr8CODxLdsRJZWKqDkV2WTZpWWG_T0HjOEXJmJR1TcmlccviX1gmlBhGuR9ZnZhwzbbcU_6NXiawi7k6ea2k6kqWh2oDsvLz1H-gwy6yRGii0da04yx6lGAbL1TQsEv4PGMoBApLtlJyiKW25SQMAIzrUY3jSv4gGB2dpoOPYCTDGLOmQr0ewWfggxENV7MQU3VNwU9SAFYjXEU4BJHq80_jX&t=eyJscyI6ImdzZW8iLCJsc2QiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tLyJ9) is giving me a differential impedance of 90-100ohms +-10% for the CSI differential pairs (table Table 10-4), while, as far as I found on the internet, the standard value seems to be 100 ohms.

So for what value should I aim? 95 ohms? 100 ohms? Something else? With what tolerance?
[image: CSI guidelines]

Comment: Sometimes while a specifiation for a bus states what the impedance should be, in practice some design guides for chips using that bus states a different impedance for practical reasons. I can't suggest what you should do but there is a chance that the Jetson design guide has a good reason to suggest what it does.

Comment: So going for 95 ohms 5% should be a reasonable value ?(in the middle of the range for the Jetson, and still within the tolerance for 100 ohms 10%)

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a suitable impedance is a complex decision taken based on

1. Space complexity(Lower impedance -> wider trace -> Poor component density)
2. Crosstalk(Tightly coupled differential traces -> More crosstalk -> More component density)
3. Series/parallel/vdd termination(affects noise margin & cost availability)

In your case, it's preferred to go for lower impedance if the design, cost & space allows. It's better to do a SI(Signal integrity) simulation before finalizing the impedance.

Comment: What a non answer.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know my answer looked like AI-generated.....